# Spring Graphql Resolvers

Tags: graphql, graphql-java, apollo-federation, graphql-federation

Is there a way in graphql to only return a result record in an list if the key is found in 2 resolvers.

```
For example:

Query {
  getData:[A!]!
}

Service A resolver
type A @key(fields: "id") {

  id:ID!
    
}

Service B resolver
type A @key(fields: "id") {

  id:ID! @external

  status:String 

}
```

Is there a way not add the record from to the list if status is null?
Only add the record to the response if the ID exists in service A and service B.

Comment: What does the resolver code for `getData` look like?  These sorts of dependent queries can't be expressed in the GraphQL language itself, but it should be straightforward to include it in the resolver.